# How to get modifier position?

Tags: python, modifiers

I need to check if the modifier.name for example "Subdivison" on the top of the modifiers stack

```
if modifier.name position == 0:
  print('Modifier "Subdivison" at the beginning of the stack')
else:
  print('Modifier "Subdivison" somewhere in the stack')
```

something like this

Comment: Hi, @APEC.. could you repost your solution as an answer, and accept it, so folks know not to try again, and others know where to find it in future? Thanks

Comment: @RobinBetts: not apecs fault, i copied the solution in it ;)

Comment: I ask Chris to make a post and edit my original message. And then I accept it as a solution. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Cheers, all, for whatever it is you're up to :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out:

The modifiers are just sorted in an array where the first is on position 0, the second on position 1 and so on.

```
import bpy
  
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        if o.modifiers:
            if o.modifiers[0].type == "SOLIDIFY":
                print("solidify modifier is on top for", o.name)
```

shorter version for python shorties.... ;)

```
tops = [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects 
    if o.type == 'MESH' and o.modifiers 
    and o.modifiers[0].type == "SOLIDIFY"]

for o in tops:
    print("solidify modifier is on top for", o.name)
```

Comment: What if name contain *.001. *.002 so with `if "Subdivison" in modifier.name`. For example I apply a modifier and I need if it on the top then print: 1, if somewhere in the stack, then print: 2

Comment: if you apply a modifier, it will be deleted from the array and i cannot be on top anymore.

Comment: @APEC: i am not sure what you mean, can you give a bit more explained example? what name? objects name? modifiers name? i don't understand, sorry.

Comment: [Hmmmm.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).. :)

Comment: never mind, all fine! Thank you!

Comment: @RobinBetts: what do you mean? i NEVER had a line too long...never...ever...ever...(just for you :))

Comment: @RobinBetts: by the way? How can you count that fast until 72!?

Comment: @Chris `echo 'this is a string' | wc -m`

Comment: OMG……….

Comment: @batFINGER: thank you! can I format this anyhow automatically or have I to do this manually? hope, it's better now

Comment: Many text editors have this available I use [spacevim](https://spacevim.org/use-vim-as-a-python-ide/)

Comment: Thanks, i will try that

Comment: @batFINGER We will be seeing Chris at the next Vim-Users Anonymous meeting, then?. "Hello, I'm Chris, and I'm a Vim user... It all started with a comment in BSE...,"

Comment: Hope not... Would you be my mentor at BSE Anon?

Comment: is it possible to add if Lattice modifier to check for lattice object name? `tops = [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects 
    if o.type == 'MESH' and o.modifiers 
    and o.modifiers[0].type == "LATTICE" and o.modifiers.object == "Some Name"]`

Comment: I am not on my computer right now but I would say, yes, should be possible

Comment: Just test it ;)

Comment: hm, yes, but with [0] as previous. Thx! =)

Comment: Of course - sorry, couldn’t test 